# Xbootclasspath/p equivalent for JAR Manifest.MF?

Tags: java, jar, classpath, manifest.mf

I currently run my JAR (which overrides default JRE classes) using command-line parameters like

```
java -Xbootclasspath/p:lib/1.jar;lib/2.jar -jar myJAR.jar
```

I would like to put those overrides into the JAR Manifest.MF like

```
Boot-Class-Path: lib/1.jar lib/2.jar
```

but that does not seem to work at all.

How can I get the same functionality using Manifest.MF?

Comment: why do you need to have these on the boot path?

Comment: to override default JRE classes

Comment: Have you found a solution?